# In MySQL select query, checking for a string or checking for true in a where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench, where-clause

Consider the following table:

```
SELECT id, Bill_Freq, Paid_From, Paid_To, Paid_Dt, rev_code FROM psr_20160708091408;
```

[image]

The requirement is to fetch the row which has `rev_code` populated with the string **`SUM`**.
I've also noticed that for every row with `rev_code` populated as **`SUM`** its `Bill_Freq` won't be either null or zero.

So I wrote two queries to fetch the row with the lowest id

Query based on string check in where clause:

```
select
        min(id) as head_id,
        bill_freq,
        Paid_From,
        Paid_To,
        Paid_Dt
from
    `psr_20160708091408` where rev_code = "**SUM**";
```

Query based on true condition:

```
select
    min(id) as head_id,
        bill_freq,
        Paid_From,
        Paid_To,
        Paid_Dt
from
    `psr_20160708091408` where bill_freq;
```

I haven't seen anyone use the second type, would like to know its reliability and circumstance of failure.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "second type" you mean a `where` clause with no explicit condition, then there is a good reason why you do not see it.

The SQL standard -- and most databases -- require explicit conditions in the `where`.  MySQL allows the shorthand that you use but it really means:

```
where not billing_freq <=> 0
```

or equivalently:

```
where billing_freq <> 0 or billing_freq is null
```

(The `<=>` is the null-safe comparison operator.

The more important issue with your query is the `min()`.  I presume that you actually want this:

```
select p.*
from psr_20160708091408 p
where rev_code = '**SUM**'
order by id
limit 1;
```

Also, you should use single quotes as string delimiters.  That is the ANSI standard and there is rarely any reason to use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use the second type of query, but as your requirement is based on **rev_code**, it is always good to have condition with **rev_code**, because of 2 reasons

1. Bill_Freq having no NUlls or Zeros might be assumption based on current data
2. Even if it is true, in future, your application logic might change and it might have a scenario having NULL or zero, which will break your logic in future.

So my suggestion is to use first query with **Rev_code**

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use below query

```
select
        id,
        bill_freq,
        Paid_From,
        Paid_To,
        Paid_Dt
from
    `psr_20160708091408` where  rev_code = "**SUM**" ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement says it itself.

> The requirement is to fetch the row which has rev_code populated with
>   the string '**SUM**'

In the scenario that bill_freq IS **NOT** NULL and `rev_code` is populated with
the string `'**SUM**'` then your logic will obviously fail.

Go for

```
where rev_code = "**SUM**";
```